# How to make a configuration json file in vue?

Tags: vuejs2

How would I go about creating a JSON configuration file that is available during development and build in Vue?

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config - simply, just read the docs

Comment: how do i import the file into my component?